# Reading all headers of an exchange without transmitting payload

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I would like to generate some statistics on massage traffic on one exchange based on header information, mainly routing key but ideally also other headers. Due to the large bandwidth involved I would like to not actually transmit the payload but only look at the header. I am looking at continuous traffic rates, not snapshot queue states.

Is this something that could be done with a specific configuration and an external program or would one have to approach this as a RabbitMQ plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be best approached as a plugin.